# Why is echo producing a newline?

Tags: bash, echo

What's the difference between

```
echo -n "
> "
```

and

```
echo -n ""
```

The first one produces a newline whereas the second doesn't.

I'm running GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Edit : I get that the input gets a newline here. I should have been clearer with the question. Consider the following script `input.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n $1
```

The following doesn't produce a newline.

```
./input.sh "
> "
```

Comment: You are indeed writing the new line, so of course it is being produced.

Comment: `-n` means "don't append newline", but in the second case you are writing one

Comment: Maybe you meant to use a continuation line(s)?

Comment: If `$1` isn't quoted, the newline is removed as part of word-splitting after the parameter is expanded.

Comment: @chepner What exactly does $1 contain in the case above, since I can't reproduce the effect using : `newline = "\n"; echo -n $newline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @chepner's comment. Consider this:

```
$ set -- "
"

$ echo -n "$1" | od -c
0000000  \n
0000001

$ echo -n $1 | od -c
0000000
```

When you leave the variable unquoted, any leading or trailing sequences of whitespace are removed by shell. So bash discards your newline when you don't quote $1. This happens *before* "echo" is invoked, so "echo -n" is given *no arguments*.

From the [Word Splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) section in the manual:

> If `IFS` is unset, or its value is exactly `<space><tab><newline>`, the default, then sequences of `<space>`, `<tab>`, and `<newline>` at the beginning and end of the results of the previous expansions are ignored, and any sequence of `IFS` characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit words.

Answer (score 3):

The string

```
"
 > "
```

has a newline in it as far as bash is concerned. The `-n` flag just means that echo will not print an extra newline at the end of your output. It will still reproduce your input, including newlines.